# EJB 2.x to 3.x automatic migration tool

Tags: ejb, code-migration

Could someone recommend me an automatic migration tool for EJB? 
Preferably some Eclipse plugin... Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four years ago I wrote some tooling in perl. But from todays perspective I think going through the sources in a day, removing unneeded stuff and adding annotations by someone who has seen both technologies is the best.

It is at the end not enough to just put @Stateless into a bean class that had its stateless definition in xml before - you also want to use @EJB annotations to inject other beans and most likely remove old CMP or BMP data access with JPA, which uses a different semantics etc.

While some tooling may exist, I think best is going over the existing source with a fine comb so that you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I suppose that the wisest approach would be to do migration manually...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using IntelliJ EJB refactoring tools:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/migrating-to-ejb-3-0.html

Comment: Also have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120804/are-there-any-ejb-migration-tools-available-for-migrating-ejb-2-1-toejb-3-x

Comment: This IntelliJ's refactoring sounds great. Since I'm Eclipse user, I was not aware of such possibility... Anyway, I have already performed my migration manually, but I will certainly try it out. Thanx!